# VB.NET: Tableadapter stored procedure that selects an image type is very slow

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

The following SQL is taking forever when it's run from the VB.net `TableAdapter`
(using SQL Server).

By commenting out the `Thumb` column, it works quickly. The datatype of the `Thumb` column is `image`.

```
SELECT 
    ID, FirstName, LastName, DOB, Gender, Thumb
FROM 
    [server].[db].dbo.[view]
WHERE 
    ID NOT IN (SELECT id 
               FROM [table a] i 
               INNER JOIN [table b] ON a.ID = b.id)
```

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Are the `[server].[db].dbo.[view]` and `[table a]` and `[table b]` on the same server?